# Blender games on Amazon Fire Tv

Tags: scripting, game-engine

I am interested in putting 3d blender games on the tv and I thought there might be a way to put it on Amazon Fire tv. I understand that fire tv takes mostly java games, but I like blender as a rendering and game engine, and I don't want to have to use another game engine. So my question is, is there a way to put blender games on the Amazon Fire tv?

Comment: I have made my question more clear. Thank you for the suggestion!